# Parallelism in C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I read that .NET C# has task and data parallelism built in. If I run a for/foreach loop in my program in a computer that has 4 cores (4 windows the Windows Task Manager), will the loop be evenly distributed into the 4 cores? If not, why isn't the for/foreach loop doesn't run in 4 cores parallel in default?

Generally speaking, is parallelism better than conventional programming? Does the benefits outweigh the drawbacks? I'm doing a lot of data processing (bunch of pulls, for/foreach loops)  and need to complete these for/foreach loops faster.

Comment: Don't know enough about C# to post an answer, but you should look into Parallel.ForEach (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

it's not running on 4 cores because it is not efficent or needed every time.

it's depending on your program and the load of your program. it's not efficent to parallelize a function that did not take 1ms/cycle. if you do a lot of long running calcuations or searches over a big field of data that can be splitted up sensible you could / should parallelize your loops.

for that topic i recommend reading [http://www.amazon.com/Multi-Core-Programming-Increasing-Performance-Multi-threading/dp/0976483246/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1336440123&sr=8-2-fkmr0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0976483246)

Comment: No, it's not running on four cores because it wasn't coded that way!

Comment: Lol why is this the accepted answer and at same time -2 votes xd?

Answer (score 4):

> If I run a for/foreach loop in my program in a computer that has 4 cores (4 windows the Windows Task Manager), will the loop be evenly distributed into the 4 cores?

Do you mean will the task be automatically parallelized over the cores? No. For that you need to use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) such as Parallel.ForEach.

> Generally speaking, is parallelism better than conventional programming?

It depends.

> Does the benefits outweigh the drawbacks?

It depends.

> I'm doing a lot of data processing (bunch of pulls, for/foreach loops) and need to complete these for/foreach loops faster.

Stop guessing that parellelization is your answer. Get out a profiler and find out where the bottleneck is. Parellelization won't help if, for example, the slowness stems from having to talk to a database over a network connection. It *might* help if the bottleneck are operations within the loop and those operations are parallelizable.

Comment: The data is being pulled from SQL Server and MongoDB, so parallelism won't be that effective? How would you optimize this scenario where the data is being pulled from database? I'm doing caching much as possible.

Comment: I don't know, you didn't give me enough information. I doubt that parallelization will help you that much; your bottleneck is the database. But you didn't tell me exactly what you're doing, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: It is doing data processing and it pulls the basic index from SQL Server and gets the actual object from MongoDB. Inside the for/foreach loop it deserializes the object and it looks at the object inside. Inside the loop there is a constant pulling from database and deserialization of object by getting the GUID of object from the database. The loop terminates until the upper limit is hit or all the necessary data is looped through.

Comment: I think the database pull and deserialization is time consuming things for sure. If the loop was basic integers and strings, it would be much faster.

Comment: "I think... time consuming things for sure" is wrong sentence for performance question. It is essentially not possible to "think" what would be faster - one need to try and measure. Possible exception is when code is using wrong algorithms altogether - O(n^2) instead of O(n), but even such cases results may be surprising with actual measurements.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation specifically for parallel processing (as @xbonez states).

.Net 4.0 does have an excellent parallel library (MSDN: [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)).